# How do i plot a timeseries graph with the following data i have

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, time-series

```
datehashtag_count = testing2.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='M'))['hashtags'].value_counts()
print(datehashtag_count)
```

```
date        hashtags              
2021-01-31  ['gme'                    16322
            ['gme']                   13691
            ['amc'                     4762
            ['robinhood'               1723
            ['wallstreetbets'          1690
                                      ...  
2021-12-31  ['wallstreet'                 1
            ['wearethestockmarket'        1
            ['whatdoyoubelieveln'         1
            ['xela'                       1
            ['zom'                        1
Name: hashtags, Length: 7106, dtype: int64
```

How do i plot a timeseries graph with the following values i got, using the column 'date' , 'hashtags' and the hashtags count.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this ?

```
import seaborn as sns 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
datehashtag_count = testing2.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='M'))['hashtags'].value_counts()
print(datehashtag_count)
datehastag_count = datehashtag_count.reset_index()
datehashtag_count.set_axis(['date', 'hashtag' , 'count' ], axis = 1 )
plt.figure()
sns.lineplot(x = 'date', y='count', hue='hastag', data=datehashtag_count)
plt.show()
```

Haven't tested the code. Don't have an equivalent dataset to work on, but this should work.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. I tried and got this error "TypeError: Cannot reset_index inplace on a Series to create a DataFrame"

Comment: Yes, thats expected. Sorry, I didn't realize the value_counts returns a series. Have edited the code. Please try the same

Comment: Hi thanks for replying. I tried and got this error "ValueError: cannot insert hashtags, already exists" and the error was pointing to this line of code "datehastag_count = datehashtag_count.reset_index()"